# XPATH for Dynamic Drop Down Arrows based on Selenium GUI

Tags: selenium, user-interface, xpath, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am new to this GUI Scripting.... My requirement is I want to click on the drop down arrow, & inside there are some elemets with tree structure to select the particular node/alarm..

So Intially I need to crack the XPATH for the drop down arrow of "COUNTERS" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N9Js.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U04J.png)
Tired Xpath by using absolute Xpath as below :

```
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 70).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                        "/html/body/div/pm-application/epic-layout/div/div/div/div[5]/div[4]/epic-layout-panel/div/div/div/pm-reporting/epic-layout/div/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/epic-layout-panel/div/pm-tree-wrapper/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/span/i")))
```

Also with Relative paths as well :

1. ```
          WebDriverWait(self.driver, 70).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='1483f603-ed09-6586-16e8-fc074ea8f908']//span//i[@class='icon tree-node-arrow collapsed']")))
   ```
2. ```
          WebDriverWait(self.driver, 70).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                        "//*[@class='virtual-tree']//*[@class='icon tree-node-arrow collapsed']")))
   ```
3. WebDriverWait(self.driver, 70).until(
   EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
   "//i[@class='icon tree-node-arrow expanded']")))

But still I am facing below issue , Please help me to resolve this issues

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Comment: Provided code lines cannot be a reason for provided exception trace. Show exact line that causes the exception

Comment: I have added the full html code in Screenshot, please have a look

Comment: No need to check HTML code. Show your code. Exception is quite clear: you're trying to call method `find_element` from string object. Show code line with `find_element`. Also show what is `EC` in your code

Comment: Below is the code I'm using

Comment: def search_counter_in_performance_manager(self):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 70).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='1483f603-ed09-6586-16e8-fc074ea8f908']//span//i[@class='icon tree-node-arrow collapsed']")))
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 70).until(
        except BaseException:
            logger.fatal("Fatal exception occurred inside Search Counter In PM()".format(self.name))
            logger.error(traceback.print_exc())

In this Xcode Path includes numbers not the string

Comment: Element with locator //div[@id='1483f603-ed09-6586-16e8-fc074ea8f908']//span//i not found. This issue I'm facing....Is this the proper way of creating Dynamic Xpath ..Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: `1483f603-ed09-6586-16e8-fc074ea8f908` looks like dynamic `@id`, so you should not use it. Try different selector without using `@id`

Answer (score 0):

Please read about CSS selectors and Xpath selectors. Both of them don't like white or empty spaces.

It is a good practice to give Selenium the element actual tag, and not just asterisk sign.

Here is an example of the find element using CSS selector:

- "div[class*='tree-node']"

This selector will return all the div elements that their class attribute contains the phrase "tree-node".

Using xpath you can find element by their attributes as well, or by the text written inside them:

- "//div[contains(text(),'333')]"

This selector will give all div elements that have the text 333 inside them